# iOS Constraints - center image and dynamic text

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

What is the best way to center an image and a label with dynamic text (so dynamic height) inside a scrollview in iOS?[image: My layout]

What constraints do I have to add? I really cant figure out how its working, maybe I cant handle it because I'am an Android-developer and from my point of view its easier to design guis with android. But thats not the point of this question.

I would be SO thankful, if somebody could explain me what constraints I have to add. The text is dynamically loaded, so the height is not fix. Due to this, my view should be scrollable (for this purpose I've added a scrollview).

**Update:**

I've tried the following constraints as recommended here. But its still not working.

This is what I did.

[[image: what I did with the image[2]]
[image: what I did with the label]

But its still not working like it should ...

[image: how it look like in simulator (iPhone 5s)]

Comment: Do you want the image vertically centre too ? i mean at exactly centre of the screen ?

Comment: No, it should be above the text, centered horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For image, give constraints as in the following image :

[image]
For label, give constraints as in the following image :
[image]

Select the imageview/label, and on the bottom right of Xcode, there's an icon Ass New Constraints, as in the screenshot, you can add top,left,right and bottom constraints here.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but how can I create "Bottom/Top/Trailing/Leading Space" ? I've tried to drag it from my image with clicked [CTRL] and then click on "Top" (for example) but it creates a "Align top to: " ... not "Space"

Comment: I have added a new screenshot. Please try.  You can also try links/ tutorials like https://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints for more details on how to add constraints.

Comment: Thank YOU so much! No really, THANK YOU! It worked! :)

Comment: @Max Lebold No mention :)

Answer (score 1):

Just center the UIImageView to the superview:

```
Align Center X to: Superview 
Align Center Y to: Superview
```

And then align the UILabel / UITextView:

```
Top Space to: YourImageView 
Leading Space to: Superview
Trailing Space to: Superview 
//or
Align Center X to: YourImageView
```

Comment: Align Center X to: Superview is "Horizontally in Container" right? When I open the "Align" menu?

Comment: @MaxLebold You have errors, read my answer. You are aligning the TOP of the UIImageView to the label, but you should align the TOP of the label to the UIImageview. Also, when using a UIScrollView, things will get REALLY messy if you don't have a UIView inside the Scrollview as a main view. Add a UIView to the scrollview, set Leading-Trailing-Top-Bottom to scrollView  0 - 0 - 0 - 0 . And inside this UIView , add your UIImageView and UILabel as subView to the UIView, and att the constraints as I showed in my answer to the UIView instead of the scrollView.

Comment: @MaxLebold No worries! :)